# PayPal TransactionID missing from GetExpressCheckoutDetails response

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using PayPal's GetExpressCheckoutDetails call with a valid token to try and pull the details of a submitted transaction. However, the returned values are a very small subset of what PayPal says should be returned according to their documentation listed at the URL below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Does anybody know why PayPal isn't returning the complete set of data? I don't care so much about most of it in this case, but we need the transaction ID, listed in the documetation as *PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TRANSACTIONID* so that we can match transactions in our database up with PayPal's transaction history.

**paypalfunctions.php (relevent functions)**

```
function GetShippingDetails( $token ) {
    $nvpstr="&TOKEN=" . $token;
    $resArray=hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails",$nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING") {   
        $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
        } 
    return $resArray;
    }

function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr) {
    global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
    global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
    global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
    global $sBNCode;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    if($USE_PROXY)
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT); 

    $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $nvpResArray=deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray=deformatNVP($nvpreq);
    $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
        $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);
        } else {
        curl_close($ch);
        }

    return $nvpResArray;
    }

function deformatNVP($nvpstr) {
    $intial=0;
    $nvpArray = array();

    while(strlen($nvpstr)) {
        $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

        $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
        $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
        $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
        }
    return $nvpArray;
    }
```

**ExpressCheckoutReceipt.php**

```
session_start();
ini_set( "session.bug_compat_warn", "off" );
require_once("paypalfunctions.php");

if ( isset( $_GET['token'] ) ) {
    $token = $_GET['token'];
    }

if ( $token != "" ) {
    $resArray = GetShippingDetails( $token );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $resArray );
    echo "</pre>";
    } else {
    echo "Error: Transaction Incomplete";
    }
```

**Returned Array (real info removed)**

As you can see, this returned array does not contain a Transaction ID. In fact, all of the newer *n* type variables that PayPal claims will be returned are missing.

```
    array(21) {
["TOKEN"]=>
  string(20) "EC-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["TIMESTAMP"]=>
  string(20) "2014-12-04T22:10:46Z"
  ["CORRELATIONID"]=>
  string(13) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["ACK"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["VERSION"]=>
  string(3) "2.3"
  ["BUILD"]=>
  string(8) "14086142"
  ["EMAIL"]=>
  string(31) "test@test.com"
  ["PAYERID"]=>
  string(13) "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ["PAYERSTATUS"]=>
  string(8) "verified"
  ["BUSINESS"]=>
  string(25) "TestCo"
  ["FIRSTNAME"]=>
  string(9) "Test"
  ["LASTNAME"]=>
  string(6) "Test"
  ["COUNTRYCODE"]=>
  string(2) "US"
  ["SHIPTONAME"]=>
  string(25) "Test Test"
  ["SHIPTOSTREET"]=>
  string(20) "123 Test St."
  ["SHIPTOCITY"]=>
  string(6) "Test City"
  ["SHIPTOSTATE"]=>
  string(2) "CA"
  ["SHIPTOZIP"]=>
  string(5) "33333"
  ["SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE"]=>
  string(2) "US"
  ["SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME"]=>
  string(13) "United States"
  ["ADDRESSSTATUS"]=>
  string(9) "Confirmed"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can read the comments in the function of `getShippingDetails()` it says `the authorization is not a completed transaction at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize the transaction`

```
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
        //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
        //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
        //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
        //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
        //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
        //' the transaction
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
```

So you also need to call `ConfirmPayment()` method after this which will call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` in the function

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much! I don't know how I missed that, but I added a call to DoExpressCheckoutPayment (with the ConfirmPayment function) after this and now everything falls into place - TransactionID is returned, though still not in the format PayPal talks about - that documentation page must be for something else.

Comment: You need to look at [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) documentation for `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete the Express Checkout transaction by completing DoExpressCheckout operation first? Every transaction in PayPal needs to be completed first before transaction ID is issued. In this case, DoExpressCheckout needs to be run before you can get the transaction ID in GetExpressCheckout details.